# How can I resize an image without using .resize() in python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have the enlarge ratio provided, like two times in width, three times in height.

Here's my thought, I want to go through each pixel in the image, enlarge all of them by ratio and put them in a new created picture.

Comment: What's the objection to using 'resize()` please?

Comment: The whole point of using a library like `PIL` or `Pillow` is that you don't have to implement such functions, they've already done the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your thought is the first step. There is some other steps. The most important step is [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

For example, if you want to enlarge a image with 2 pixels in width, 2 pixels in height to 4 pixel in width and height. As your thought, you should let

```py
new_img[0][0] = old_img[0][0]
new_img[2][0] = old_img[1][0]
new_img[0][2] = old_img[0][1]
new_img[2][2] = old_img[1][1]
```

But only 4 pixels' value are assigned, what is the value of the other 12 pixels? You have to provide an algorithm to interpolate.

You can find more information from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation).